# Test if an IP is being used in an internal network without using nmap

Tags: linux, networking, security, bash, nmap

I can perform port scan using `nmap` to test if a given IP is being used, e.g.

```
nmap -PR 192.168.1.9
```

However, nmap is not installed in most server, is it possible to have the same result (e.g. check if the particular IP is being used) without installing `nmap`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use ping:

```
ping 192.168.1.9
```

Most of the machines will reply, but some wont. If it's in the same local network, you can check the arp (after a no-reply):

```
arp -n |  grep 192.168.1.9
```

(-n shows numeric IP addresses - does not try to resolve hostnames)

Comment: Possibly a stupid question, but would `arp` be installed when `nmap` isn't?

Comment: I think arp is by default found on almost all devices that are able to communicate in a switched network. i.e. you'll find it already installed on most devices AFAIK..

Comment: @amyassin, technically your comment isn't correct. ARP is a component of the TCP/IP protocol suite. It's not a function of the type of network the host is connected to. Any host that uses the TCP/IP suite will use ARP and presumably has a tool for testing ARP. I could run my hosts on IPX/SPX in my switched network, they would all communicate just fine, and ARP would never be seen as it's not a component of IPX/SPX.

Comment: @joeqwerty You are right, by switched network I meant TCP/IP and that was wrong. Sometimes I forget that there are other than TCP/IP :)

Comment: No worries. I just wanted to add some clarification.

Answer (score 4):

I assume there is some reason why `ping 192.168.1.9` is unacceptable?  If you're looking for a device that might be firewalled, but is on the local broadcst network, `ping 192.168.1.9` followed by `arp -a -n|grep 192.168.1.9` can be a more reliable way of finding an otherwise-silent host.